# HTML parser in Python without using external libraries

Tags: python, html, parsing, crud

I've been assigned a problem at university.

The problem is as follows:

I have to make a program, in a language of my choice(I decide on Python since I'm most comfortable in it), that takes an HTML file name as input, parses it(if such exists), and allows CRUD operations on it. The catch is that I can't use external libraries or packages, only ones that I've written.

How should I approach the parser?

I'd have to have a structure in which I can save the parsed data. I was thinking about a list of tuples, each tuple consisting of the opening tag, the content, and the closing tag(if there is one), or discarding the closing tags altogether and focusing on the opening ones and the content. About the parser, I was thinking to read the file's content into a string variable and try to separate the different tags and their content. I don't know, if either of those is a good idea, or if there is a better way that I haven't considered.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking, "how do I start?" are too broad to be on topic here. And questions that are primarily opinion-based are off topic because they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "How to parse" and "What should the parsed data look like" are really orthogonal questions. The second question is far and away the most important, and I suggest you try to set thoughts about parsing aside while you figure out what the data structure looks like. You could, for example, write some test cases for the CRUD operations themselves, and then try to implement the operations. You should be able to do all of that without a parser, since you could just start with an empty HTML tree and then build it up using your API.